# How to return value of $(window).resize()

Tags: jquery, function, dom

I would like to get a certain height and add via .css() to another element in the DOM. (Hope I am using the term DOM right in this context). 
I thought I could get the value through a function in which the value of the height is calculated first and then returned.

But I guess the value is not returned outside the function, since I can't see in the console with console.log but I guess I have a mistake in the code since I am quite new to jQuery.

```
function heightBackgroundGap() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var backgroundGap = $('.start').height() - $('.clip-path-container').width();
        return backgroundGap;
    });
}

$('.background-gap').css('height', heightBackgroundGap);
```

Comment: `resize()` is establishing an event handler.  It will happen in the future.  It's effectively asynchronous logic.  You cannot return in a procedural pattern.  You need to move your final `css()` logic *inside* the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're trying to do, but as Taplar said in his comment, this line:

`$('.background-gap').css('height', heightBackgroundGap);`

is only executed once in your code. It sets a window.resize event that runs every time the window is resized, but it doesn't actually re-set the CSS. You want something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).resize(function() {
        var backgroundGap = $('.start').height() - $('.clip-path-container').width();
        $('.background-gap').css('height', backgroundGap );
    });
});
```

That will set up a function that will run every time the window is resized and specifically sets the CSS property as part of it. I also put it in a document.ready event You should always put items like this in a document.ready, because your CSS may not have been fully processed and rendered before you check the height. Make sure things are ready to be measured before checking them.

Comment: Thanks @HBlackorby, but this only works while I resize the window, then .background-gap gets the right height. But it actually should keep the right height after I resized the window. So basically > calculate the height I need, when resized > give me the value > add it to .background-gap after resizing is done

Comment: Sorry for the hassel, actually it works with the $(window).resize(), just with:

var backgroundGap = $('.start').height() - $('.clip-path-container').width();
$('.background-gap').css('height', backgroundGap );

Comment: Sure, you may need to calculate it once on page load. It might be useful to put the calculation into a function, call it once on document.ready and then put it in the window.resize event to call again if the window is resized.